# HTML scripting not loading JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to display piechart in UIWebview of my iOS xcode project, for that I'm using jqplot with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, the issue I face is JavaScript file "devicepiechart.js" is loading from the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script>
            function load()
            {
                alert("I am an loading scripts!");
            }
        </script>

<script src="devicepiechart.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload= "load()">
</body>
</html>
```

The `load()` function alert is shown properly without any problem. I could detect that my `.js` file is not loading as I have the `alert("string");` function in my `.js` file too for debugging.

UPDATED devicepiechart.js, and I hope the external `.js` file may not have any error, because I have the source from this http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

```
$(document).ready(function()
      {
              alert("good");
              var data = [
                          ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14],
                          ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
                          ];
              var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data],
                                         {
                                         seriesDefaults: {
                                         // Make this a pie chart.
                                         renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                                         rendererOptions: {
                                         // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                                         // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                                         showDataLabels: true
                                         }
                                         }, 
                                         legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
                                         }
                                         );
              });
```

Comment: If loading *inline* scripts works but loading script files doesn't, that pretty firmly points to a problem loading the file. (Or, of course, there's a serious error in the external script -- which you haven't shown -- preventing it from being parsed successfully.)

Comment: Side note: Neither `language` nor `type` is necessary. `language` has been deprecated for well more than a decade. `type`'s default is and always has been `text/javascript`. So...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, As u said I have deleted the language and type from my html, even then the same result and I have updated my question by including the javascript file, please refer to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, while opening my html file in browser, all the alerts are displaying as expected but in xcode ios its not loading, what should be changed for clearing that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load all your .js files into "copy bundle resources" of project Targets "bulid phases" , now the piechart is running successfully in ios simulator.

Comment: Please elaborate on this. I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery before the other js loads

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sathya: It was definitely missing (though why runelynx pointed you at such an out of date version is unclear). Perhaps you added it in the wrong place. It goes **before** the tag loading your file.

Comment: and yes, be sure to put it before all other javascript <scripts> :)

Comment: @runelynx, ya I used before javascripts.Then too the alert in js file is not working. And I was trying to include the devicepiechart.js file in the html file within the <script> tag, then the alert function is working.